# check Box in drop down list flutter

Tags: flutter, checkbox, flutter-layout

I am using check Box in drop down Menu but when I chose the box nothing change unless closing the menu and open it again here is my code

```
items: [
DropdownMenuItem(
child: Row(
children: <Widget>[
Checkbox(
onChanged: (bool value) {
setState(() {
isSat = value;});},
value: isSat,),
Text(
daysList[0]['days'],),],),),
DropdownMenuItem(
child: Row(
children: <Widget>[
Checkbox(
onChanged: (bool value) {
setState(() {
isFri = value;});},
value: isFri,),
Text(
daysList[6]['days'],),],),)
].toList(),
onChanged: (value) {},),
```

Comment: Are you using statelesswidget?

Comment: no  I am using StatefulWidget

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to wrap all your checkboxes with `StatefulBuilder`. The `setState` that you're using only applies to the state of the widget containing all your dropdown menus but not the state of the checkbox.

Here how you can do it:

```dart
 StatefulBuilder(
    builder: (BuildContext context, StateSetter stateSetter) {
      return Checkbox(
        onChanged: (bool value) {
          // note here we call stateSetter from the StatefulBuilder!
          stateSetter(() {
              // reverse the value
              isFri = !isFri;
         });
        },
        value: isFri,
       );
  }),
```

You've to do it for each `CheckBox` widget.